# How to read javascript file in frontend javascript/browser

Tags: javascript

Please read carefully before marking as dupe.

I want to read a `javascript` file on frontend. The `javascript` file is obviously being used as a script on the webpage. I want to read that javascript file as text, and verify if correct version of it is being loaded in the browser. From different chunks of text in the js file, I can identify what version is actually being used in the end user's browser. The js file is `main.js` which is generated by angular build.

I know we can do something like creating a global variable for version or some mature version management. But currently, on production site, that will mean a new release, which is couple of months from now. Only option I have right now is html/js page, which can be directly served from production site, without waiting for new release.

So my question is, is it possible we can read a javascript file as text in hmtl/js code in the browser.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430557/how-to-make-sure-browsers-load-the-most-recent-version-of-a-file-after-updating

Comment: Load the script into tag with type of non-HTML5 script type, ex. `type="text/plain"`. That way the script not executed, and you can get the text content to verify the version. Then you can create a new script element dynamically (with correct version details in `src`) and load the script.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use a proper version management system on your server, though, checking the version at the client feels a bit hackish.

Comment: @Daniel I want to read the js file as text, and from different components in that js file I will be able to detect the version of js file being loaded on frontend. Just want to make sure if correct version is beingloaded

Comment: @Teemu thanks for suggestion. May you please put that as an answer?

Comment: I rather not answer with a hack ; ). Like said, you should rather put effort on proper version management on your server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an idea can be :

1. use `fetch` api to get a container that can be use to async load the script
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
2. use `text()` method which return a promise to get text content

   ```
   fetch('http://localhost:8100/scripts.js').then((res) => res.text()).then(scriptContent => {
     // scriptContent contain the content of your script
     // if (scriptContent.includes('version : 1.1.1')
     console.log(scriptContent);
   });
   ```

Comment: But does it fetch fresh copy from the server, or makes use of browser cached copy?

Comment: by default yes you have cache. But you can pass a second argument to fetch to force not have cache `fetch("some.json", {cache: "no-store"})` https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/03/referrer-and-cache-control-apis-for-fetch/

Answer (score 1):

this is absolutely not an efficient way, but since you want to work without any new version release or working with a version management system

here is the thing
assume file's checksum (md5 sha125 or anything) of V1.0 equals X and you will calculate before the coding part.

```
if checksum(X) != X{
location.reload() 
}
```

would help for a security features too since it's an important project.

another way of controlling this situation is changing the main.js file's name if it is possible.